# Android: LinkedIn OAuth Callback not Working

Tags: android, oauth

I'm using LinkedIn `OAuth` in my Android app. I've an LinkedIn application, consumer key and secret already, an as a result I can request succesfully.

Everything is fine until callback. The web page not calling back, I mean `onNewIntent` or `onResume` methods not calling.  Web page only shows callback url with parameters. I mean it looks like:

```
callback_url://?oauth_token=324sdf&oath_verifier=as21dsf
```

Here is my all code:

```
try {
    consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret");
provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken", "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken", "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize");
    final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startActivity(intent);                          
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Activity is already defined as `singleInstance` in `Manifest`.

What's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer myself after a long research.

I've changed my base class to `linkedin-j` which can be looked at [here](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/).

Then set this constans as below:

```
    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "ConsumerKey";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "ConsumerSecret";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "callback";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + ":///";
```

And initialize like that:

```
LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
LinkedInApiClient client;

liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
startActivity(i);
```

This callbacks well and I've handled at OnNewIntent:

```
String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
client.postNetworkUpdate("Test");
```

That's all.

Comment: Hi Martin, I had lots of search and demo testing, fail with all examples, now at your post, I would like to know first, does your code work with android 4.0 and above ?

Comment: Can you post an update whether your code works with Android 4.0 above. In Addition to that please share your AndroidManifest.xml also because I am getting an ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCEME after I enter the details and press enter on my LinkedIn WebView.